# The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first (Activity with fragment and ViewPager)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

### I create this post because i can't solve this problem. My idea its a Fragment activity that on the top has a fragment that is a map and on the bottom has a view pager that allows user to swipe through fragments with information.

---

**Main Activity (Fragment Activity)**

```
public class RestaurantDetails extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "ImageGridActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.restaurantinfo);
    inicialize();

            /* Adding fragment in a relativelayout */
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG) == null) {
        final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, new MapFragment(), TAG);
        ft.commit();
    }

        /* Pager on bottom */
        mPager.setCurrentItem(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("idRest"));
}
```

---

**Layout Main Activity**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

      <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="212dp"
        tools:context=".MapFragment" />


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pagerDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

**Map Fragment**

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        context = getActivity();

        mapLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.ipmaps, container, false);

        locationImage = (ImageView) mapLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.ipmaps_my_location_img_view);

        setupIpMapsGenericResources();

        return locationImage;
    }
}
```

---

**Map Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ipmaps_relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e1e1e1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/ipmaps_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ipmaps_my_location_img_view"
        android:src="@drawable/compasso"
        android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

I also have tried instead of adding the fragment in a Relative Layout add him on a  element but with no success. I am desperated for help. After the program run the method onCreateView in the MapFragment he throws this error: "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are returning the `ImageView` in `MapFragment`'s `onCreateView()`. You should return `mapLayout` since it is the root `ViewGroup` of the hierarchy.

Also, you are calling `super.onCreateView()`. By doing so, you are calling `MapFragment` parent's `onCreateView()`which returns null by default.

As a tip, you should avoid giving your classes names that are also shared with classes provided by the framework.